# Problems getting my info from table join to display in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

{Connecting 2 tables together (with teacher ID and teacher name)

I have created the join and I have tested in SQL. Seems good.  I am trying to print it on the screen.

```
$classandteacher = "SELECT person_name FROM people RIGHT OUTER JOIN classes ON classes.instructor_id=people.instructor_id ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $classandteacher){

            while($row = mysqli_query($dbc, $result));

            $teacher = $row["person_name"];
            echo ("Teacher: " . $teacher . "<br>");}
```

Comment: ooh... `;` after while

Comment: It makes no sense to OUTER JOIN a table from which you select no columns

Answer (score 0):

It's because the While Loop isn't correctly formatted.

Remove the `;` and put it into `{}`

You also need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` to get the `Array` from the query

```
$classandteacher = "SELECT person_name FROM people RIGHT OUTER JOIN classes ON classes.instructor_id=people.instructor_id ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $classandteacher);

    if(!$result) { //If your MYSQL query is throwing an error
       error_log(mysqli_error());
    }


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      $teacher = $row["person_name"];
      echo "Teacher: " . $teacher . "<br>";
     }
```

Comment: Any errors being outputted? You might want to check if `$result` is returning with `FALSE` and then use `mysqli_error()` to see if there is a problem with your query - see updated answer

Comment: No errors. The connection is good. The select statement is good.

Comment: Sorry can't be much more help without any errors! Make sure your error reporting is turned on. `error_reporting(1)`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Or try using 
    mysqli_fetch_array  instead

```
$classandteacher = 
"SELECT 
person_name FROM 
people RIGHT OUTER     JOIN classes ON 
classes.instructor_id
=
peopleinstructor_id     ASC";
$result =  
mysqli_query($dbc,$     classandteacher);
if(!$result) { //If 
your MYSQL query is 
throwing an error
error_log(mysqli_er
ror() );}
while($row = 
mysqli_fetch_array(
$result))
{
 $teacher = $row
["person_name"];
  echo "Teacher: " . $
teacher . "<br>"; }
```